# How to declare an attribute ID in XML

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm writing some XML and an XSD as an assignment...
In my XML i have a tag called `a` ( not actual name) and attribute called `id`. Part of my XML is shown below:

```
    <a id="1">
    ...........
    </a>
    <a id="1">
    ............
    </a>
```

When I validate using XSD it doesn't give an error....

```
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string" />
```

I tried to use xsd:ID as a data type of attribute `id` but it gave me an error; I couldn't figure out what the problem is.

How can I do this?

Comment: So you do not get an error if you assign the xsd, but you do if you do not assign one?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should go back to using `type="xsd:ID"`. What this does in addition to making sure that the value is unique is that it will also allow you to use `xsd:IDREF` for referencing.

The error you're getting when you try to use `xsd:ID` is that an ID value must start with a letter. If you change your ID's to something like "ID-1"/"ID-2" or "a1"/"a2", it will work fine.

Example Schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="doc">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="a"/>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="b"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="a">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:attribute name="id" use="required" type="xsd:ID"/>
        </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="b">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:attribute name="idref" use="required" type="xsd:IDREF"/>
        </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Example XML:

```
<doc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Untitled1.xsd">
  <a id="ID-1">
    ...........
  </a>
  <a id="ID-2">
    ............
  </a>
  <b idref="ID-1"/>
</doc>
```

Comment: How can i add some text to my xml to specify that for every element the attribute id is of type xsd:ID?
Is possible to embed this declaration inside the doc itself?

Comment: [This (somewhat dated) article](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/11/20/schemas.html?page=3) discusses using `key`, `keyref`, `unique` over `ID` and `IDREF`. Any comments on that?

Answer (score 2):

"1" is a valid string, so validation does not return an error.
If you want to specify some restriction (e.g. "id should starts with a letter"), you have to declare your type and specify the pattern:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="myID">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="[a-zA-Z].*"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
....
  <xsd:attribute name="id" type="myID"/>
....
```

If you want to specify the uniqueness restriction, you can use the xsd:unique element like this:

```
<xsd:element name="root" type="myList">
  <xsd:unique name="myId">
    <xsd:selector xpath="./a"/>
    <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
  </xsd:unique>
</xsd:element>
```

This will mean that element "root" declared as some "myList" should contain subelements "a" with unique attributes "id"

Comment: what i want is to have an id attribute for each element and make sure each value of id is unique

Comment: I've just added a comment about xsd:unique feature. It will help you.

Answer (score -1):

ID attribute type in XML file must start with letters and some limited special characters.

try this type of IDs in the XML file for example:

...........
    
    
    ............